# How to Deal with Enumeration with hash table

Tags: java

In Java, we can use an enumeration to cycle through a Hash Table.  But the Java compiler complains that the Enumeration variable us a raw type.

Here is the code:

```
Hashtable <Integer, Integer> Myhash = new Hashtable <Integer, Integer>();
Enumeration e;
e = MyHash.values();
```

The compiler complains that the Enumeration is of a raw type.  How do we define the code so this is not so?

Answer (score 3):

There are a few problems with your code:

1. You're using a raw type. Your variable should declare its generic type parameter:

   ```
   Enumeration<Integer> e;
   ```
2. `Hashtable.values()` returns `Collection`, not `Enumeration`. You probably want this:

   ```
   e = MyHash.elements();
   ```
3. `Hashtable` and `Enumeration` have been obsolete for years. Unless it's for backwards compatibility, you should be using `HashMap` and `Iterator` instead.

Comment: I have tried hashMap.  There is still an issue.  Iterator has the same issue as the Enumerator in the compiler in the fact that they both can not be raw code.

Comment: And the solution is the same for both. Don't use the raw type.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Enumeration e = Collections.enumeration(MyHash);
```

Comment: That still does not work.  But it is a good guess.  It produces a different kind of error.  It says it is missing type arguments for generic class.